# identify digits coming from noise/shadow displays

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I've been warming my head for a while on how to be able to identify the top numbers of various displays.
[multiple displays to be read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnirZ.png)

About the detection of the displays I made a pink mask to detect the displays using HSV. The problem is when I will treat these displays to get the numbers from above, it always comes with noise at the edge of the display, usually the problem is the shadow because the display is deep or the edges are pink.
[low noise display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18FN2.png)

What I'm doing to solve is to crop the image by the points that I consider to be constantly empty and I try to remove what the threshould identifies, because if something is identified it will probably be a shadow / noise, I do this for the upper left and lower right regions to try to filter the display.
[threshould for noise removal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj861.png)

In this example I took one that fails to demonstrate the poorly done clipping that can occur when I try to filter it. After this filter, when I get the region of interest for reading the digits, the number does not appear complete, which makes it impossible to identify it.
[incomplete digit classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOUjn.png)

However, when the filter is unable to remove the edges correctly, they appear in the number identification part, which also makes the correct result impossible.
[display filter failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs71i.png)

The program I made ends up working only for situations where the digits are not touching the edge of the display and are well lit.

I would like to know if there is a way that I can more easily identify the upper digits of the various displays.

My program is similar to that of the (link below) but with displays that are somewhat difficult to deal with.
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/

Sorry if my English was bad, I had help from the Google translator

Comment: Try division normalization. Search this forum. I have posted several examples. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663469/manage-a-text-detector-which-is-very-sensitive-to-lighting-conditions/64668119#64668119

Comment: probably if it were a lighter shadow it would solve .. but the situation here could be a shadow or a piece of the edge that gets in the way .. and if it is a shadow its darkness matches the black color of the digit, I believe that "division normalization" does not work for this case .. (I may be mistaken)